# Epinions extended dataset search

Tags: data-request, social-media

I am looking for the extended version Epinions dataset. The [Librec Project](http://www.librec.net/datasets.html), extended opinions dataset is no available on this site (link is dead).

Do you know the current link for this repository? Or the other source of the Epinions data in the extended version?

#### Checked repositories

I know these repos, however they don't have the Epinions extended:

- Project RED (liris.cnrs.fr/red/)
- Snap: Epinions dataset (snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-Epinions1.html)

#### Edit:

Doesn't work means: "The www.trustlet.org page isn’t working"

Comment: What is "*doesn't work*"? Please [edit] your question and be **specific**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dr. Jiliang Tang](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~tangjili/trust.html) provides a raw data download of a scrape of the Epinions site. I am unfamiliar with the fields you are looking for, but this [data link provides 283 MB of data](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~tangjili/Epinions.rar).